# Re-writing code - does not function

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I'm trying to rewrite an existing code CODE 1 using mysqli functions (CODE 2). But it's not working. Could someone help rectify this problem?

CODE 1 (old code - works)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['thename']) === true && empty($_POST['thename']) === false) {
    require'../db/connection.php';

    $query = ("SELECT 'photos'.'theurl' FROM 'photos' WHERE 'photos'.'thename' = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['thename'])) . "'");

    echo(mysql_num_rows($query) !== 0) ? mysql_result($query, 0, 'theurl') : 'Not found';
```

CODE 2 (new - not working)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['thename']) === true && empty($_POST['thename']) === false) {
    $getVal = mysqli_real_escape_string($Conn_db, trim($_POST['thename']));

    require_once('../db/connection.php');
    $query = ("SELECT 'photos'.'theurl' FROM 'photos' WHERE 'photos'.'thename' = '" . $getVal . "'");
    $result = mysqli_query($Conn_db, $query);

    $queryA = ("SELECT id FROM photos");
    $resultA = mysqli_query($Conn_db, $queryA);
    $row_cnt = $resultA->num_rows;

    echo($row_cnt !== 0) ? mysqli_result($result, '0', 'theurl') : 'Not found.';
} 

function mysqli_result($result, $ro, $field) { 
    $result->data_seek($ro); 
    $datarow = $result->fetch_array(); 
    return $datarow[$field]; 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Do you see any errors?

Comment: are you getting an error? "not working" is not specific enough

Comment: The database connection needs to be intiialized before calling `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. Move your `require_once()` before defining `$getVal`.

Comment: I wonder if I ever see a php user who'll be able to use mysqli without that dirty mysql_result hack and thousand other useless functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your codes make very little sense either in mysql and mysqli part.

Better rewrite it to [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql):

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['thename'])) {
    require'../db/safemysql.class.php';
    $db  = new safeMysql();

    $url = $db->getOne("SELECT theurl FROM photos WHERE thename = ?s", $_POST['thename']);
    echo ($url) ? $url : 'Not found';    
}
```

Comment: I've never used SafeMySQL before. This would be a ideal start. Thanks. Isn't 'mysqli_real_escape_string' required any more for the $_POST tags?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the order of the following lines:

```
$getVal = mysqli_real_escape_string($Conn_db, trim($_POST['thename']));

require_once('../db/connection.php');
```

It should be done as below because `mysqli_real_escpae_string()` requires the database connection to be created before being called:

```
require_once('../db/connection.php');
$getVal = mysqli_real_escape_string($Conn_db, trim($_POST['thename']));
```